# how to show date time in datetime picker according to timezone using datetimepicker of anuglarjs indrimuska

Tags: angularjs

I want to set min-date option on datetimepicker and also want to set this option according to the timezone of selected location.
for example :

$scope.minDate = moment().subtract(0, 'month');

but this statement set minDate according to local time instead of selected location timezone. Please, anyone, tell me the solution that how can i set minDate according to the timezone and  how to solve this problem because I need the solution

I am using angularjs and its indrimuska plugin to show datetimepicker.

Here is the [link of the documentation](https://github.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) for getting a date for your desired timezone. Like in the following example

```
$scope.minDate = getDateFromTimezone('America/New_York');

function getDateFromTimezone (employeetimeZone) {
       return moment().tz( employeetimeZone).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
    }
```